# путь к картинке через :src

Tags: vue.js, webpack

```
<div>
  <img src="./img/no_photo.jpg> <!-- это работает -->
  <img :src="path"> <!-- это нет -->
 </div>
```

...

```
data() {
    return {
        path: './img/no_photo.jpg'
    }
}
```

использую vue-cli > webpack

если смотреть код в браузере то путь первой картинки преобразовывает в `src="/static/img/no_photo.4836f67.jpg"`, а путь второй картинки получаеться `src="./img/no_photo.jpg"`

как сделать так что б вебпак мог и пути из переменных преобразовывать в рабочие

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать require: `path: require('./img/no_photo.jpg')`

Comment: ERROR in ./~/babel-loader/lib!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/comp/ShowListItem.vue
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './img/no_photo.jpg' in 'C:\Users\dimka\Desktop\vue\learn_router\src\comp'
 @ ./~/babel-loader/lib!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/comp/ShowListItem.vue 30:21-50
 @ ./src/comp/ShowListItem.vue
 @ ./~/babel-loader/lib!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/comp/ShowsList.vue
 @ ./src/comp/ShowsList.vue
 @ ./src/router/index.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi ./build/dev-client ./src/main.js

Comment: возможно он его просто не находит. Проверьте, что у вас путь к изображению относительно файла, в котором path объявлен правильно указан. Или приведите скриншот структуры проекта.

Comment: https://github.com/rudnik275/vue-js-learning/blob/a6e406bc8721955895b4b0544511f0dcba1c79a3/src/comp/ShowListItem.vue#L38

Comment: вот так попробуйте: noPhoto: require('./../../img/no_photo.jpg')

Comment: http://joxi.ru/4AkQDqnHMKwqwm

Comment: попытка №2:  noPhoto: require('./../img/no_photo.jpg')

Comment: да, так работает, спасибо, а скажите пожалуйста почему это работает?))

Comment: Смысл в том, что вэбпак при сборке заменит это выражение, вызвав соответствующий лоадер(в данном случае file-loader) и в итоге вернет корректный путь согласно своим настройкам. Сам путь в вашем варианте задается относительно ShowListItem.vue, соответственно, в пути добавляем ./../. У вас кстати в вэбпаке есть алиас для src папки, поэтому можно еще вот так написать: require('@/img/no_photo.jpg')